# Selenium + JUnit, Assertion error of proper page loaded

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I've written a code using Selenium WD and JUnit that should check if proper page is loaded and the table of this page is not null

Besides assertion, to make sure that proper page is loaded (checking if URL contains specified text), I've put "if-else" statement in "waitUntilPageLoaded" method.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class GuruSearch
{
    @Test
    static void checkDemoLogin()
 {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pansa\\Documents\\Webdrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/");
    TestCase.assertFalse(driver.getPageSource().contains("404"));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //odczekaj(5000);
    WebElement browser  = driver.findElement(By.name("emailid"));
    browser.sendKeys("Test@test.com");
    browser.submit();
    waitUntilPageLoaded(driver,"access.php", 10);
    TestCase.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Access details to demo site"));
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
    TestCase.assertNotNull(table);
    driver.close();

}

static private void odczekaj(int czas)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(czas);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Przerwanie");
    }
}

private static void waitUntilPageLoaded(FirefoxDriver d, String zawiera, int timeout)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, timeout);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(zawiera));

if (d.getCurrentUrl().contains(zawiera))
    {
    System.out.println("OK");
    }
else
    {
    System.out.println("NOK");
    }
}
}
```

The "if-else" statement in "waitUntilPageLoaded" method returns "OK", but         TestCase.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Access details to demo site")) 
throws AssertionError, although the text appears in the page.
Why there is AssertionError thrown?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the JUnit annotations, the annotated method shouldn't be static. I have modified your code a bit, try the below:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class GuruSearch
{
    @Test
    public void checkDemoLogin()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/");
        TestCase.assertFalse(driver.getPageSource().contains("404"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //odczekaj(5000);
        WebElement browser  = driver.findElement(By.name("emailid"));
        browser.sendKeys("Test@test.com");
        browser.submit();
        waitUntilPageLoaded(driver,"access.php", 30);
        TestCase.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Access details to demo site"));
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
        TestCase.assertNotNull(table);
        driver.close();
    }

    static private void odczekaj(int czas)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(czas);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Przerwanie");
        }
    }

    private static void waitUntilPageLoaded(WebDriver d, String zawiera, int timeout)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(zawiera));

        if (d.getCurrentUrl().contains(zawiera))
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NOK");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is printing 'OK' and Assert condition also passing. And I think, it doesn't matter if we give upper/lower case in the contains. It will match both the cases.

I don't have Firefox in my system so I have checked with Chrome, you change the browser and try... I hope it helps...

Comment: Didn't work, also "Access" has a capital "A" in page content.

Comment: @pansalva I have modified the code and executed as well but in the Chrome browser. You try in the Firefox and let's see still you are facing that issue or not...